# Getting wrong dot counts in Owl Carousel 2.3.4

Tags: owl-carousel

I am getting wrong dot count with Owl Carousel when I remove auto width it worked fine but when I set auto width it getting me wrong dot count.

The wrong Count like I set a total of 8 images on my carousel and it shows me 8 dots instance of 4(I set setting like items: 2, and slideBy: 2)

[LIVE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net//vsnpq9u0/17) : Check with Desktop Resolution.

HTML:

```
<div id=”client-testimonialslider” class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#client-testimonialslider').owlCarousel({
    rtl:true,
    loop:true,
    nav:false,
    margin:30,
    items: 2,
    slideBy: 2,
    itemsDesktopSmall : [900,1], // betweem 900px and 601px
    itemsTablet: [700,1], // 2 items between 600 and 480
    itemsMobile : [479,1] , // 1 item between 479 and 0
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:10000,
    responsive:{
       0:{
            items:1,
            slideBy: 1
        },
        600:{
            items:1,
            slideBy: 1
        },
        992:{
            items:2,
            slideBy: 1,
            autoWidth:true
        },
        1201:{
            items:3,
            autoWidth:true
        },
        1400:{
            items:1,
            autoWidth:true
        },
        1600:{
            items:3,
            autoWidth:true
        },
        1800:{
            items:3,
            autoWidth:true
        },
        2000:{
            items:4,
            autoWidth:true
        }
    }
});
});
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "dotsEach" option to specify the number of dots per item.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    "dots": true,
    "dotsEach": 1
});
```